# Checking for key violations in Access append query

Tags: sql, ms-access, key

I'm trying to append a table to another table, and I receive a key violation error.

> "Microsoft Access can't append all the records in the append query.
>   Microsoft Access set 0 field(s) to Null due to a type conversion
>   failure, and it didn't add 26 record(s) to the table due to key
>   violations, 0 record(s) due to lock violations, and 0 record(s) due to
>   validation rule violations. DO you want to run the action query
>   anyway?"

How can I tell Access where SPECIFICALLY these key violations are occurring? It's hard for me to scroll through this and resolve everything.

Comment: Need the table schemas and the query to even start giving you an answer. Should be easy to identify the bad guys though.

Answer (score 1):

you can detect the 26 conflicts with a simple [inner join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208854%28v=office.12%29.aspx):

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA
   INNER JOIN tableB
      ON tableA.keyColumn = tableB.keyColumn
```

Comment: Cool. So to delete these conflicts, here's what I think I'd do. I'd do  DELETE * FROM existingTable WHERE (SELECT * FROM existingTable INNER JOIN incomingDataTable ON existingTable.key = incomingDataTable.key). Right?

Comment: By the way, can I assume that these key conflicts are duplicates I'm trying to import?

Comment: You gave 0 descrption of the 2 tables so in general you cannot assume that they are duplocates

Answer (score 1):

If your able resides on SQL Server and you are accessing it via Access, you need to resync the link with link manager.

In some cases you need to set all columns to allow nulls as this error will show up after you resync the link.

I run into this a lot backtracking/legacy .txt files for impromptu reports.